# Trigger multicondition DataTrigger not working?

Tags: wpf, themes, datatrigger

I'm stuck on something and hope an easy answer.  First, I have a theme that has a multibinding trigger.

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
  <DataTrigger.Binding>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}" >
      <Binding Path=".TemplatedParent" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
      <Binding Path="IsEnabled" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </DataTrigger.Binding>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NewBackgroundColor}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource NewBorderBrushColor}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

My data controls textboxes, comboboxes have the INotifyPropertyChanged implemented.

During the processing, under certain conditions, I want to raise the event that "IsEnabled" changed, but not actually changing its value.  So, the multibinding never gets triggered.  Since the first parameter to the converter is the control object itself, it never "changes", so it's just there to ride-along as a parameter to the converter to work with.

The only way to actually fire the trigger is to do something like

```
MyControl.IsEnabled = false;
MyControl.IsEnabled = true;
```

Is there some other way to force triggering a multi-binding data trigger?

Try to elaborate a little bit more on my issue.  I have subclassed basic controls (textbox, combobox, buttons, etc) to add certain settings / functionality, etc.  For commonality to them, they all support "IMyCommonInterface" interface.  Without having to redefine the entire "Theme" (in example, simple textbox), I want to conditionally change colors like doing a data validation, but more than just simple color changing of these sample properties.

Since the basic textbox does not have any idea of the "IMyCommonInterface", nor the custom properties, I have created a converter class "MyConverter" that takes the actual control object as the first parameter.  Now, within the coverter, I can do

```
if( values[0] is IMyCommonInterface )
```

I can then typecast to the interface and check all for ANY special condition I want without having to explicitly create say.. a dozen triggers each based on A+B or A+C or ( A+B NOT C) OR D, etc.

So, I didn't want to have a bunch of different themes, a bunch of triggers, etc, just a centralized element to work with.  I'm looking into other alternatives, but if I ran into an instance that just throwing a PropertyChanged event doesn't force the data trigger either, I'd rather find out now while still trying to understand all the (expletive) hooks that .Net has, and that you can basically point to almost ANYTHING.

Comment: Are you sure `Path=".TemplatedParent"` is correct? Perhaps you want `<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>`

Comment: @Vlad, well noted, but yes, it is correct.  I actually found that by accident when I was learning multi-part binding.  If you pass the path of "." it returns the object.  Since the dot is the toggle button of combo, the .TemplatedParent passes the actual entire combobox control.  Again, it works otherwise if I force the IsEnabled to false and back to true, so I know its "wired" ok.

Comment: this is a very interesting question - quite a puzzle. My question to you, is it possible to get details what you trying to accomplish by such trigger. Your mind is in solution space of the problem that you have created. I am wondering is there another way to get the effects that avoids this problem?

Comment: @denismorozov, expanded answer.

Comment: What is the extra functionality you're adding?  Subclassing controls (especially in WPF) is rarely the best solution, in my experience...  With functionality like that provided by an attached DependencyProperty you may be able to offer the same features with much cleaner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just an idea...

Since you already subclassed your basic controls. Why not add there yet another property. You can add a bool DependencyProperty (let's call it "IsTriggered") as well as method that toggles that property

```
public void ReEvaluateTrigger()
{
    IsTriggered = !IsTriggered;
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTriggeredProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsTriggered", typeof(bool), typeof(ButtonEx), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

public bool IsTriggered
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTriggeredProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsTriggeredProperty, value); }
}
```

then at a necessary time, under whatever your conditions may be all you would have to do in your code is call myControl.

```
MyControl.ReEvaluateTrigger()
```

which should cause the trigger to reevaluate:

```
 ...taken from your code with a change to binding to IsTriggered
 <Binding Path="IsTriggered" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
```

I put this in my quick test, just to see if IsEnabled would toggle (I know it's simple, but it's just a quick test):

```
<Button Content="push to trigger enabled below" Click="Button_Click"/>
<Sample:ButtonEx x:Name="ButtonToBeTriggered"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsTriggered, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            Content="ButtonToBeTriggered" Width="100" Height="50" Margin="50"/>

//where in code behind
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonToBeTriggered.ReEvaluateTrigger();
    }
```

in the test, I extended

public class ButtonEx : Button

where I created ReEvaluateTrigger() as well as the trigger...
Anyway, just an idea!